# Get custom attribute value in Magento2 product page

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have created one custom attribute through code, in admin product edit page,but i wolud like to display that value in product detail page,

How to get the custom attribute collection in product detail page magento2.

i have tried with the below code but it is giving an error:

```
$_attributeValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute ($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on boolean in
```

Help me thankful

Thanks

Comment: try this $_product->getData('your_attribute');

Comment: Make sure the attribute exist for the product you're getting, guess that would be the issue @shiivashankarm

Comment: Thanks @PrathapGunasekaran issue with value only now the value is getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_attributeValue = $_product->getCustomAttribute($_code)
```

Will give the custom attribute value if $_product is repository object.

If it is a model object you can refer to @Rakesh Donga's comment

Comment: If your issue is solved. Please accept this as answer. @shiivashankarm

Comment: Hi @bhargav, iam calling custom phtml file to product view page like the code: <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content" >
            <block
                    class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\test"
                    name="reward_frontend_msg"
                    template="Vendor_Module::product/view/test.phtml" before="product.info.addtocart"/>
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: but it is calling for newly created products previosly existing products it is not displaying

Comment: Can you share the Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\test block code?

Comment: Please find the link  to block code: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267766/magento-2-custom-phtml-file-not-calling-to-all-products-view-pages